# Why is RStudio giving an error when using plotFun from the Mosaic package?

Tags: rstudio, r-mosaic

My students are using the Mosaic package for RStudio, and one of them is not able to use the function plotFun. Every time she tries to use it, she gets the same error. For example,

```
> plotFun(x+2~x)
Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE) : 
cannot coerce class ‘"formula"’ to a data.frame
```

Are there any thoughts as to what is going wrong? She will need to use this function often for this class; is she missing a package or update of R or RStudio?